# CXF - Collision in the ObjectFactory class doing with JAXB Binding

Tags: jaxb, cxf

I already solved the problem using the -p parameter in the wsdl2java command line to put the namespace conflict in other package, but after I tried I was incapable to do this using the JAXB Binding.

How is the correct form to use binding?

I have the following wsdl:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://com.foo.ws/FicherosVehiculosWS/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ax21="http://com.foo.ws/FicherosVehiculosWS/xsd" xmlns:tns="http://com.foo.ws/FicherosVehiculosWS/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl">
   <wsdl:documentation>FicherosVehiculosWS</wsdl:documentation>
   <wsdl:types>
      <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://com.foo.ws/FicherosVehiculosWS/">
         <xs:import namespace="http://com.foo.ws/FicherosVehiculosWS/xsd"/>
         <xs:element name="consultaMarcasRequest">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="ax21:claveSubtipoVehiculo"/>
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="ax21:claveCategoriaCirculacion"/>
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="ax21:claveGrupoEstadistico"/>
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="ax21:claveClasificacion"/>
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="ax21:modelo"/>
               </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="consultaMarcasResponse">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="ax21:marcas"/>
               </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
      </xs:schema>
      <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://com.foo.ws/FicherosVehiculosWS/">
         <xs:import namespace="http://com.foo.ws/FicherosVehiculosWS/xsd"/>
         <xs:element name="consultaSubtipoVehiculoResponse">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="tns:subtipoVehiculo"/>
               </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="subtipoVehiculo">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element ref="ax21:claveSubtipoVehiculo"/>
                  <xs:element ref="tns:descSubtipoVehiculo"/>
               </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="claveSubtipoVehiculo" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="descSubtipoVehiculo" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:schema>
      <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://com.foo.ws/FicherosVehiculosWS/xsd">
         <xs:element name="marcas">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element ref="ax21:claveMarca"/>
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="descMarca" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
               </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="version">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="claveVersion" type="xs:string"/>
                  <xs:element name="descVersion" type="xs:string"/>
               </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="descripcion" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="claveClasificacion" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="modelo" type="xs:int"/>
         <xs:element name="claveSubtipoVehiculo" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="claveCategoriaCirculacion" type="xs:integer"/>
         <xs:element name="claveGrupoEstadistico" type="xs:integer"/>
         <xs:element name="claveMarca" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="descClasificacion" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:schema>
   </wsdl:types>
   <wsdl:message name="consultarMarcasRequest">
      <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:consultaMarcasRequest"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="consultarMarcasResponse">
      <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:consultaMarcasResponse"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:portType name="FicherosVehiculosWSPortType">
      <wsdl:operation name="consultarMarcasOperation">
         <wsdl:input message="tns:consultarMarcasRequest" wsaw:Action="http://com.foo.ws/FicherosVehiculosWS/consultarMarcasOperation"/>
         <wsdl:output message="tns:consultarMarcasResponse" wsaw:Action="http://com.foo.ws/FicherosVehiculosWS/FicherosVehiculosWSPortType/consultarMarcasOperationResponse"/>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:portType>
   <wsdl:binding name="FicherosVehiculosWSSOAP" type="tns:FicherosVehiculosWSPortType">
      <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:operation name="consultarMarcasOperation">
         <soap:operation soapAction="http://com.foo.ws/FicherosVehiculosWS/consultarMarcasOperation" style="document"/>
         <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:binding>
   <wsdl:service name="FicherosVehiculosWS">
      <wsdl:port name="FicherosVehiculosWSSOAP" binding="tns:FicherosVehiculosWSSOAP">
         <soap:address location="http://com.foo.ws/"/>
      </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The `FicherosVehiculosWS` schema and the `FicherosVehiculosWS/xsd` refer to the same property `claveSubtipoVehiculo` and the collision happens.

I tried the next three solutions to override the problem using JAXB binding, only to receive the same error but this time as a JAXB Throw error. What did I do wrong?

**Template 1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jaxws:bindings wsdlLocation="http://127.0.0.1/FicherosVehiculosWS.wsdl"
          xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
          xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema[@targetNamespace='http://com.foo.ws/FicherosVehiculosWS/xsd']">
    <jxb:package name="mx.axa.ventadirecta.stub.bancs.ficheroauto.xsd"/>
  </jaxws:bindings>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

**Template 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jaxws:bindings wsdlLocation="http://127.0.0.1/FicherosVehiculosWS.wsdl"
          xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
          xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <jaxws:bindings  node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema[@targetNamespace='http://com.foo.ws/FicherosVehiculosWS/xsd']">
    <!-- Customize the package name that is generated for each schema -->
    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='claveSubtipoVehiculo']">
      <!-- rename the value element -->
      <nameXmlTransform>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="ax21:subtipoVehiculo"/>
      </nameXmlTransform>
    </jxb:bindings>
  </jaxws:bindings>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

**Template 3**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jaxws:bindings wsdlLocation="http://127.0.0.1/FicherosVehiculosWS.wsdl"
          xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
          xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <jaxws:bindings  node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema[@targetNamespace='http://com.foo.ws/FicherosVehiculosWS/xsd']">
    <!-- Customize the package name that is generated for each schema -->
    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='consultaSubtipoVehiculoResponse']//xs:complexType//xs:sequence//xs:element[@ref='tns:subtipoVehiculo']">
      <!-- rename the value element -->
        <jxb:class name="DescSubtipoVehiculo" />
    </jxb:bindings>
  </jaxws:bindings>
</jaxws:bindings>
```